# DVI-D Splitter Not Working with GeForce 8400gs

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, vga, dvi

I have a GeForce 8400gs and it has a DVI and VGA port on the back. I was using dual monitors with one VGA and one DVI cable. I wanted both displays to be digital so I bought a DVI-D splitter and put one DVI cable in each monitor, connected them to the splitter and put the single merged connection in the back of the cards DVI connection.

It will not recognize the second monitor (I'm not even sure how it determined which one was the first monitor). The tech specs state that it supports "Two dual-link DVI outputs for digital flat panel display resolutions up to 2560x1600" http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_8400_tech_specs.html.

Do I need a different converter or is my only option for dual monitors with this card one VGA, one DVI?

Comment: That link states that 8400 series has "One single-link DVI output". Also, splitters usually just mirror the signal to two displays.

Comment: Oh, that 4 was a superscript for the footnotes at the bottom, I missed that. So if it just has One single-link my only options are VGA for the 2nd monitor or convert a DVI to VGA?

Comment: Yes, with that graphics card you are limited to your existing arrangement: one monitor using DVI, the other using VGA. You *could* convert the VGA output to DVI-A, but it would still be analogue, so there's not much point (unless the 2nd monitor only had a DVI port).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to use two DVI connections.  You need to purchase a video card with two DVI connections.

•Two dual-link DVI outputs for digital flat panel display resolutions up to 2560x16004

The following feature is only on the 8600, it clearly states this, on the page you linked too.

•One single-link DVI outputs for digital flat panel display resolutions up to 1920x120066 is on the 8400 only.

•One dual-link DVI outputs for digital flat panel display resolutions up to 2560x16005 is on the 8500 only.

•Two dual-link DVI outputs for digital flat panel display resolutions up to 2560x16004 is on the 8600 only.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Dual link DVI Splitter ( Part # VDA-3). If your video card is DVI Dual link and you have Dual Link monitors then the best option is to buy a Dual Link DVI Splitter.